# How to find videos that have free reuse license types on the web?

Tags: webvideos

Google Image Search provides a very handy method for isolating specific license types:
[image: license type]

Is there anything like this for videos?  I've been shooting blanks so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this is on YouTube by adding a filter under the "Features" header. E.g.:

[image: youtube filter example]

Also found that Vimeo offers similar search functionality when you add filters on the right:
[image: vimeo example]

Specifically on Vimeo these each mean:

- CC0: Public Domain Dedication
- CC BY-NC-ND: Attribution Non-Commercial No Derivatives License
- CC BY: Attribution License
- CC BY-NC-SA: Attribution Non-Commercial Share Alike License
- CC BY-NC: Attribution Non-Commercial License
- CC BY-SA: Attribution Share Alike License
- CC BY-ND: Attribution No Derivatives License

Comment: Note that, as always, you should make sure that the video really is free to use - sometimes videos come up under the YouTube creative commons search which are very obviously not creative commons.